# Do not get any alert message in Pusher

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

Trying to trigger event with help of Pusher but failed after running below code . Don't Get alert message .
Console Information:
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:ping","data":{}}
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:pong","data":{}}

Server Side Code :

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
      $options = array(
        'cluster' => 'ap2',
        'encrypted' => true
      );

      $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
        '******',
        '******',
        '****',
        $options
      );

      $data['message'] = 'hello world';
      $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);
```

Client Side Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher('*******', {
      cluster: 'ap2',
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Provided the credentials are correct, the code looks correct to me. Do you see the event appear in the debug console on the Pusher dashboard?

Comment: Occupied                           Channel: my-channel   17:31:18
Subscribed  3477.524014 Channel: my-channel   17:31:18
Connection  3477.524014 Origin: http://localhost  17:31:18           Console Output:
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:ping","data":{}}
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:pong","data":{}}

Comment: Do you see the events appear on `https://dashboard.pusher.com/apps/<APP_ID>/console/realtime_messages`?

Comment: Don't see any event after running php code

Comment: You could try printing the result of `trigger` with `$debug` turned on by doing `print_r($pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data, null, true))`.